# Arduino rosserial installation in Melodic

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-melodic, ros-lib, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have a project in which I have an IMU from which I receive data with the help of an Arduino MEGA. Now I'm trying to integrate this with ROS Melodic which I have installed in Ubuntu 18.04, I'm following the instructions provided in rosserial tutorials to [setup the Arduino IDE](https://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup). In this site it says that I need to run:

`sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosserial-arduino`

and

`sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosserial`

I've already done this.

Then, step 2.2 (catkin instructions) is very confusing to me: it says that a **ros_lib** folder was created and that "must be copied into the Arduino build environment to enable Arduino programs to interact with ROS". So I searched and found two folders with that name, one in: `/opt/ros/melodic/share/rosserial_client/src/ros_lib` and `/opt/ros/melodic/share/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib`, my question is which one of these directories is the one I need to copy? I suppose it is rosserial_arduino's one.

After that there's a **Note** telling me that I need to "delete libraries/ros_lib in order to regenerate as its existence causes an error" and that this is accomplished with:

`cd <sketchbook>/libraries`

`rm -rf ros_lib`

`rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .`

My second question is: what for do i need to copy the folder just to remove it? isn't it the same if i just go to `<sketchbook>/libraries` and run `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .`?

What are the differences between all this procedure and just installing the library from inside the Arduino IDE? I'm a novice, so the diffrence between just working on a script instead of seting up a full ROS workstation is not something I really understand

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328310/arduino-rosserial-installation-in-melodic/) by [Cardoso1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/43955/cardoso1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1 - Did you git cloned repository from tutorial ?

2 - you need to remove library in your sketchbook it should be made after catkin_make

3 - to make this library works with your own message type you need to catkin_make your workspace and then make libraries again with removing ros_lib

---

Originally posted by [khasreto](https://answers.ros.org/users/38724/khasreto/) with karma: 36 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cardoso1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/43955/cardoso1994/) on 2019-07-12**:
No, in the tutorial it says there are two options to install the libraries, the first one which is the RECOMMENDED is to install it via `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosserial-arduino` and `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosserial`.

The second option requires to git clone the repository onto the ROS workstation and catkin_make.

The first option doesn't tell anything about catkin_make, do i need to do it?